# edit-comment method returns 405 error

Tags: support

Trying to understand how [`edit-comment`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-comment) method could be used.

I passed valid token with `write_access`, valid key, and existed comment id, but all I've got is:

```
{
  "error_id": 405,
  "error_name": "key_required",
  "error_message": "`key` is required when `access_token` is passed."
}
```

Then I tried random id, key and token - [same result](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-comment#id=1&body=okay&key=2&access_token=10&preview=true&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Also I've [tried to call](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/posts/10363291/comments/add?access_token=1&body=okayokaykayokayokay&key=1&site=stackoverflow) this method via `api.stackexchange` and get another error:

```
{"error_id":404,"error_name":"no_method","error_message":"this method cannot be called this way"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

ps: I'm having similar problems with [create-comment](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-comment) and [delete-comment](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/delete-comment) methods.